# Does Entity framework check for redundant OrderBy() methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following Repository model method:

```
public IQueryable<AccountDefinition> FindAccountDefinition(string q)
{
    return entities.AccountDefinitions.Include(a => a.SDOrganization)
                                      .Where (a=> String.IsNullOrEmpty(q) || 
                                              a.ORG_NAME.ToUpper().StartsWith(q.ToUpper()))
                                      .OrderBy(a=>a.ORG_NAME);
}
```

And the following action method:

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "short", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client,VaryByHeader="X-Requested-With", VaryByParam = "*")]

public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm=null, int page = 1)
{
    //code goes here
    var accountdefinition = repository.FindAccountDefinition(searchTerm== null ? null : searchTerm.Trim())
                                      .OrderBy(a => a.ORG_NAME)
                                      .ToPagedList(page, pagesize);
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
         ViewBag.FromSearch = true;
         return PartialView("_CustomerTable",accountdefinition); 
    }
    return View(accountdefinition);
}
```

Currently I am doing the `OrderBy(a => a.ORG_NAME)` both inside the action method & inside the repository method. so how will entity framework and linq deal with this. I need to keep the `OrderBy` inside the repository method, since many other action methods are calling this repository method. and inside the action method I can not apply the `ToPagedList` unless I specify an `OrderB`. so my questions are:-

1. how will EF & linq deal with the duplicate `OrberBy`?
2. and will the `OrderBy` be done the DB level or on the server ?

Thanks

**Edit**
here is the generated sql statement from the sql profiler , and there is two OrderBy commands:-

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (15) 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[ORG_ID] AS [ORG_ID], 
[Project1].[LOG_LOGO] AS [LOG_LOGO], 
[Project1].[HEAD_LOGO] AS [HEAD_LOGO], 
[Project1].[ORG_NAME] AS [ORG_NAME], 
[Project1].[HASATTACHMENT] AS [HASATTACHMENT], 
[Project1].[LOGIN_URI] AS [LOGIN_URI], 
[Project1].[SUPPORT_EMAIL] AS [SUPPORT_EMAIL], 
[Project1].[DEFAULTSITEID] AS [DEFAULTSITEID], 
[Project1].[ORG_ID1] AS [ORG_ID1], 
[Project1].[NAME] AS [NAME], 
[Project1].[CREATEDTIME] AS [CREATEDTIME], 
[Project1].[DESCRIPTION] AS [DESCRIPTION]
FROM ( SELECT [Project1].[ORG_ID] AS [ORG_ID], [Project1].[LOG_LOGO] AS [LOG_LOGO], [Project1].[HEAD_LOGO] AS [HEAD_LOGO], [Project1].[ORG_NAME] AS [ORG_NAME], [Project1].[HASATTACHMENT] AS [HASATTACHMENT], [Project1].[LOGIN_URI] AS [LOGIN_URI], [Project1].[SUPPORT_EMAIL] AS [SUPPORT_EMAIL], [Project1].[DEFAULTSITEID] AS [DEFAULTSITEID], [Project1].[ORG_ID1] AS [ORG_ID1], [Project1].[NAME] AS [NAME], [Project1].[CREATEDTIME] AS [CREATEDTIME], [Project1].[DESCRIPTION] AS [DESCRIPTION], [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[ORG_NAME] ASC) AS [row_number]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[ORG_ID] AS [ORG_ID], 
        [Extent1].[LOG_LOGO] AS [LOG_LOGO], 
        [Extent1].[HEAD_LOGO] AS [HEAD_LOGO], 
        [Extent1].[ORG_NAME] AS [ORG_NAME], 
        [Extent1].[HASATTACHMENT] AS [HASATTACHMENT], 
        [Extent1].[LOGIN_URI] AS [LOGIN_URI], 
        [Extent1].[SUPPORT_EMAIL] AS [SUPPORT_EMAIL], 
        [Extent1].[DEFAULTSITEID] AS [DEFAULTSITEID], 
        [Extent2].[ORG_ID] AS [ORG_ID1], 
        [Extent2].[NAME] AS [NAME], 
        [Extent2].[CREATEDTIME] AS [CREATEDTIME], 
        [Extent2].[DESCRIPTION] AS [DESCRIPTION], 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[AccountDefinition] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[SDOrganization] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ORG_ID] = [Extent2].[ORG_ID]
        WHERE (@p__linq__0 IS NULL) OR (( CAST(LEN(@p__linq__0) AS int)) = 0) OR (( CAST(CHARINDEX(UPPER(@p__linq__1), UPPER([Extent1].[ORG_NAME])) AS int)) = 1)
    )  AS [Project1]
)  AS [Project1]
WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Project1].[ORG_NAME] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=NULL,@p__linq__1=NULL
```

Comment: Its done at the db level as its before your ToPagedList call.  Have you looked at the generated SQL?  I suspect it just does the order by twice.

Comment: i know that I can check the Sql profiler, but I want to understand first how the EF is suppose to work on it ? and I do not think the order of the command before the ToPagedList or after it will have any difference ..

Comment: I think it is a little dangerous to return `IQueryable<T>` from the DAL.

Comment: @Magnus , why it is dangerous ? . this approach is provided on many msdn articles and books ... can you explain ur point?

Comment: @JohnJohn Because you (might) not know how it is used after it is returned by the DAL and you have no control what kind of SQL query is generated.

Comment: but I am using Entity Framewrok to connect my asp.net mvc with the sql server. so I do not have other approach to read,edit, delte , create data to/from the Db ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) how will EF & linq deal with the duplicate OrberBy?

It will ignore the second OrderBy because the correct way to specify multiple `ORDER BY` clauses is to use OrderBy first and then use `ThenBy`

> 2) and will the OrderBy be done the DB level or on the server ?

At the DB level since you are applying it to the `IQueryable<T>` before calling `ToPagedList` which will execute the statement.

Comment: Even if `ThenBy` is used it will be stripped if it is in the same column.

Comment: you mean it will ignore the action method orderBY ?

Comment: Yes, it will ignore it if you specify it twice. I mean it will ignore the second. The SQL query will be fine.

Comment: can you check my edit , I have copies the sql profiler sql statement. and I saw two OrderBy commands.so does this mean that the orderBy is done twice ?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe it will actually ignore the first: basically the second order by will simply override the first. Otherwise you would not be able to reorder some collection that already ordered itself.

Comment: I am not sure, but the generated SQL statement  (I add it to my original question) is having two OrderBy , but not sure if this means that there are two OrderBy commands being executed in the DB ?

Comment: I am not sure why EF generate sql statements that look difficult to understand . when I look on the generate sql , I always get afraid of the performance !!

Comment: If you have some concerns about performance of the query don't hesitate to run this query through the SQL Database Engine Tuning Advisor. It will analyze the SQL query and tell you if there are some optimizations that can be made.

Comment: I always run against the sql tuning advisor ,, and I got Estimated improvement 0% . which means my sql queries are well tuned ?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you have to call `OrderBy` in your controller, because the `ToPagedList` method requires  `IOrderedQueryable` instead of `IQueryable` as the parameter, so what about returning `IOrderedQueryable<AccountDefinition>` from your repository?

```
public IOrderedQueryable<AccountDefinition> FindAccountDefinition(string q) {
  return entities.AccountDefinitions
    .Include(a => a.SDOrganization)
    .Where (a => String.IsNullOrEmpty(q) || 
                 a.ORG_NAME.ToUpper().StartsWith(q.ToUpper()))
    .OrderBy(a=>a.ORG_NAME);
}
```

`OrderBy` returns `IOrderQueryable` by default, so there is no overhead and the other methods shouldn't be affected by this change.